# How to Build a Custom ping executable to use on Android?

Tags: android, c, networking, android-ndk

On some Android devices, the executable binary `/system/bin/ping` seems to be removed.

I wonder if I can build a ping executable binary from the Android source code [ping.c](http://androidxref.com/4.0.4/xref/external/ping/Android.mk).

But when build it using `ndk-build`, some errors happened:

```
jni/ping.c:67:47: fatal error: private/android_filesystem_config.h: No such file or directory
 #include <private/android_filesystem_config.h>
                                           ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/myping/ping.o] Error 1
```

`ndk`'s include folder doesn't have file `android_filesystem_config.h`.

My question is how to build a ping executable to use?

Comment: What steps have you taken to obtain `android_filesystem_config.h` and ensure it's in a place where the compiler can find it?

Comment: I also want to point out that if you're copy/pasting code you found somewhere, you may not even need that particular include. Have you checked to see if your code actually requires methods, functions, variables, or constants from that header file? Do you know what the purpose of that header file is?

Comment: I have no detail idea about ping.c，I just want to build it.

Comment: I know the limit of raw socket on android,so I give up this idea，and just use the /system/bin/ping